# How is a hyphenation dictionary used for hyphenation?

Tags: ms-office, libreoffice, hyphenation

I've read about **hyphenation** and I came to know that the hyphenation depends on the **dictionary**, we are using for the particular language. For some words Microsoft Office hyphenates differently than LibreOffice. I tried to open the dictionary`hyph_en_US.dic` but couldn't understand the content.
What I didn't get is, how the dictionary is used.

1. Does it contain the list of words to hyphenate?
2. Does it contain the rules to decide as to how to hyphenate the word?

**Note:** I know they use algorithms as well to make the hyphenation better but to what extent does the dictionary play a role?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards,
Ankur Vashishtha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LibreOffice** like TeX and a lot of other programs use the hyphenation algorithm created by Franklin M. Liang. This algorithm uses a pattern matching technique to find hyphenation points in words. A separate dictionary file containing the patterns is used for each language. According to [Franklin M. Liang's thesis](http://www.tug.org/docs/liang/liang-thesis.pdf):

> These  patterns  find  89% of  the hyphens  in  a pocket  dictionary  word  list,  with  essentially  no  error.

As to how **Word** does it, it is hard to tell, since it is proprietary software. My guess is that it does not use such an algorithm but a real dictionary with the 100% correct hyphenation points added in. This would explain why the hyphenation is different and more accurate in Word.